# Why can't I download anything on my ZTE reef all of a sudden?

Tags: sd-card, downloading

I just bought this phone on eBay and got it on Saturday. I downloaded games, music, ringtones etc. from play store on Saturday & yesterday. Now today when I try again to download it says couldn't install on usb or sd card.

Did I mark or unmark something somewhere that could have caused this to happen or is it an internal phone problem? I'm completely dumb when it comes to phones & technology. I have no idea what almost everything on the phone means!!!

Comment: Welcome to Android Enthusiasts! Do you have an SD card inserted into your phone? How much storage is left? You can check this in *Settings › Storage*. If possible, please [edit] your question and include a screenshot of that page. That would help us narrowing down the issue.

Comment: I have a 64 g sd catd and have plenty of space left(1.5g)The phone wouldnt even.allow me to take a screenshot. so I unmounted the sd card and am now installing the app. Now that the sd card isnt mounted it let me capture the screenshot, I'm just not sure how to put the screenshot in my edited question?

Comment: When editing your question (at least with a web browser), the tool-bar on top of the text field a.o. has an "image" icon. That allows you to upload and integrate images. If that doesn't work out for you for some reason, you also can upload it manually to e.g. imgur.com and include the link; one of us then will see to integrate it with your post. Please do not forget to also include what you wanted to install when the error occured (with link to playstore, if possible).

Answer (score 1):

As suggested in the Android Central forum [post](http://forums.androidcentral.com/general-help-how/278616-error-couldn-t-install-usb-storage-sd-card.html#post3064768) follow the workaround to solve the issue,

Temporary Workaround:

- Goto `Settings-> Storage -> Unmount SD Card`.
- Now install the app from the Playstore.
- `Settings -> Storage -> Mount SD Card` and start using the app.

The above steps solved the issue for many while this is not an actual fix it should solve the problem temporarily for installing an app.

As explained in this [blog post](http://phonegist.blogspot.in/2013/08/how-to-solve-error-couldnt-install-on.html) the actual problem and has a fix for that,

Actual Fix:

The problem is caused by a temporary file called `smdl2tmp1.asec` that is used during some installations (I think of apps that are movable to SD) but does not get deleted for some reason, most notably when you run out of space. Because of this, the system can't create it and treats it as an error, rather than figuring out that it's stale and simply deleting it.

The solution is go and delete `smdl2tmp1.asec` yourself. From what I can tell, it could reside in two locations:

1. `/sdcard/.android_secure` - this is an invisible folder on your SD card, which you can access with any file manager, like ASTRO File manager.
2. `/mnt/secure/asec/` - access to this folder requires root and a program like Root Explorer

Look for `smdl2tmp1.asec` in these folders and delete any ones you see. Since it's just a temporary file deleting it seems to be a safe enough operation. Once you've done that, all the update problems should go away.

Comment: Added a solution from a blog post. That actual fix is to delete the `smdl2tmp1.asec` temp file which seems to fix the update problems permanently.

Comment: could the file have another name?  I'm not finding that exact one.

Comment: The file would've been deleted by the system automatically. Did you try to download anything from the playstore? Did the workaround fix your problem? If not fixed tell what are the files you can see under that directory?